# Как заставить Yii2 использовать свой View

Tags: php, yii2

Есть базовый класс `yii\web\View`.

Мне необходимо его расширить.

Создал класс:

```
class SMView extends View
{
    public $someProperty;
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы Yii2 по-умолчанию начал использовать этот класс вместо стандартного?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Полагаю вам нужно переопределить компонент view в конфигурации проекта.

То есть будет что-то такое

```
[
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'view' => [
            // В зависимости от расположения SMView путь/пространство имен к нему может быть не таким как указано
            'class' => 'app\components\SMView',
        ],
        // ...
    ],
]
```

[Документация](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#using-view-components)